# how to fire up the "select file" dialog box when click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying the simplify the following multiple images upload code in javascript so that when I click on "add_photo" button it will fire up the "select/browse file" dialog box. I need some help here. Thank you.

html form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    <div id="filediv"> 
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" style="visibility:hidden"/>  
        <input type="button" id="add_image" class="upload" value="Add Image";/>             
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="upload" class="upload" name="submit" value="Upload Images";"/> 
</form>
```

and what i think is the relevant javascript code function requiring modification:
.............................

```
$('#add_image').click( function()   
{ 
    $(this).before(
        $("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow')
        .append($("<input/>", {name: 'file[]', type: 'file', id:'file'}))
    );
});
```

Comment: Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.click()` on the input to programmatically open the file input dialogue. Inside your `$('#add_image').click` function, you'll need to do the following (pseudo-code):

```
let input = $('input');
input.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `click()` method to simulate click event on file input.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("input").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" />
<button>Select file</button>
```